# HTML: How common is it that different browsers render 1em at a different actual px size?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

As you know, you can specify dimensions with CSS in px or em. As far as I understand it, em means "line height of the current element's fonts". My approach currently is to always use px (also for margin which seems to be a controversial practice).

Question: **Can I rely on the ratio of px and em to be the same across browsers**? If not, then my manually specified margins between paragraphs will likely look odd because they so not match 1em anymore.

I believe that it is better to use em for margins but I have quite a base of existing code that always uses px margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you cannot.

The size of `em` in pixels is related to the font type & size you're using, the resolution of your screen (depending on OS, browser), and possible further OS and browser settings - eg "Show fonts +10%" may alter the `em` value.

Comment: There's no guaranteed relationship between `pt` and `em` either.  `em` (and its friends `ex`, `ch`, etc) depend on the font in use and can be radically different even among fonts on the same machine.

Comment: @Zack I didn't say there was ;)  The `EM` relation is only to the `PT` size of the *default desktop font* (only) not all fonts.

Comment: `em` changes depending on the font -- so clearly it cannot have any constant relation to the `pt` size of a single font. Moreover, different operating systems (and user preferences) will have different default fonts with different `em` to `pt` ratios. There is  simply no relation.

Comment: @Radomir I think the fact I'm discussing font sizes in points is throwing you all off.  `em` changes depending on all three of the font type, font size, screen resolution.  There is no constant relation, it is just initially calculated from those three values for your system.

Comment: I guess em can mean nearly everything according to "The Standard" but I am interested what will happen in practice. Probably like rolling a dice.

Comment: @Rudi Not true at all! Verbatim quote from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units : "The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property **of the element on which it is used**. The exception is when 'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which case it refers to the font size of the parent element."  (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 7):

No. `em`s are relative to the user's chosen font size, `px` aren't. The default font sizes of desktop browsers are about the same in pixels, but mobile devices in particular will vary even before user adjustment.

You should use `em` for a margin in text content that should be sized similarly to the surrounding fonts, and `px` for a margin that has to line up with images used by the page layout.