# Why is "font-size: 1em" bigger in IE10 than Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

I'm currently working on developing a site, and I can't figure out why the text displays bigger in IE10 than it does in Chrome. (I've made sure that both of the browsers are set to 100% zoom--no more, no less.)

I've got a reset in my CSS: `body { font-size: 1em; }`. In Chrome (v27.0.1453.116 m), this displays as expected--if I change that rule in the CSS to `font-size: 100%;` or `font-size: 16px;`, nothing visibly changes. This, to me, indicates that in Chrome, 1em = 16px. But the proportional font-sizes (`em` and `%`) display much bigger in IE, at what appears to be 1em = 21px.

I have two images show the difference when `body { font-size: 1em; }`, but since I don't have 10 reputation yet, I can't post the full URLs. They're hosted on imgur, though, and their filenames are as follows:

- **`font-size: 1em;` in Chrome:**

[image]

- **`font-size: 1em;` in IE10:**

[image]

If I set `font-size` using `px`, then I get consistent results--both Chrome and IE10 will display consistently. But using `px` for font sizes strikes me as less-than-preferred practice these days.

You can see the HTML and the CSS in [this jsFiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/44fha/). I included all of the CSS, which may have been a little unnecessary, but I thought it'd be better to provide more context rather than less.

Can anyone help me figure out why IE10's displaying `1em` bigger than Chrome, and what I can do about it?

Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT** - Figures that as soon as I posted this elaborate question, I'd figure out what was going on. I had set the IE zoom to 100%, but IE also has a "Text size" option that, for some reason, was set to "Largest". Setting it to "Medium" fixed the problem.

Comment: That's the browser default font size.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is happening because the respective html rendering engines are rendering that font in slightly difference ways, I'm not sure what can be done about that though.

Comment: Oh bugger, I had the IE zoom set to 100%, but apparently, IE also has a "Text Size" option that was set to "Largest". When set to "Medium," it displays as intended.

Well, that's incredibly obnoxious and embarrassing.

Comment: One "em" is the size of the letter "M" in the browser's default font. "2 em" would be twice as big. "0.5 em" would be half as big, etc. Specifying your site's measurements in ems has the nice side effect of scaling well if the user changes the default font (because they have poor vision, for example).

Comment: @Cyborgx37, try measuring the size of the letter “M”, and you will see that neither its width nor its height equals `1em`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - You are correct. My usage of the term is [outdated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)#Incorrect_and_alternative_definitions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've "solved" my own problem, 'cause I'm a fool.

IE10 has two settings, both under the "View" menu, which change the size of what's displayed. I'd made sure that the "Zoom" setting was set to 100%, but completely overlooked the "Text size" setting, which was set to "Largest". Setting it to "Medium" fixed my issue, and made it so both IE and Chrome displayed identically.

Comment: To err is human, and not particularly fool. You can accept your answer, which seems to be the correct one, even though the question was a bit confused. The problem really had nothing to do with font size settings in your code.

Comment: I think the best way to have the same font-size across different browsers is to setting a fixed font-size for the body and then using rems to change font-sizes of other elements when required.

Answer (score 2):

The size of em in pixels is related to the font type & size you're using, the resolution of your screen (depending on OS, browser), and possible further OS and browser settings - eg "Show fonts +10%" may alter the em value.

*According to Rudu in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729172/html-how-common-is-it-that-different-browsers-render-1em-at-a-different-actual).*